# How can I convert this code to prepared-statement or statement in jdbc?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert this values to a new table but eclipse doesn't read this query:

```
INSERT INTO my-list SELECT * FROM cars WHERE color='RED'
```

Comment: what is the error? Please post what you tried so far.

Comment: String query ="INSERT INTO my-list SELECT * FROM cars WHERE color='RED'"; Statement st = conn.createStatement; ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

Comment: what is the error? Please update

Comment: That gives me error: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().

Comment: do not use executeQuery() Use executeUpdate() Or execute() it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `executeUpdate()` Or `execute()` to issue data manipulation statements. `executeQuery()` is only meant for SELECT queries.

Comment: please accept it. If it worked for you.